# what is the best way to model sales taxes in rails ordering system

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I'm programming a simple invoice system.

Products have the usual: name and cost, has many Line Items. 
LineItem is a Product inside an Invoice (belongs to Product, belongs to Invoice).
Invoice has many Line Items.
Taxes have: name and rate (ex 8.25%).

**Here is the dilemma: How to setup the Taxes on the Products, the Line Items and the Invoice?**

A Product can have one or more Taxes.
Therefore, a Line Item can have one or more Taxes.

Should I create two tables: products_taxes and line_items_taxes and create two has_and_belongs_to_many_association?

Comment: Suggest you change the question title to something specific, like "what is the best way to model sales taxes in rails ordering system"

Answer (score 6):

Taxes are generally region-specific, and as such, tax rates really should be their own thing. There's no direct relationship between the taxes and the product, it's about a relationship between the tax rate and the place the item is being shipped/billed.

So, I wouldn't make any relationship between products and taxes. I would create a tax_rates table, and then define a method on the invoice model (or on the product model, if you need to do per-product taxes, which is very likely) that calculates the final price. Something like:

On the product model...

```
def calculate_final_price(tax_rate)
  price*(1+tax_rate.tax_percentage)
end
```

Comment: Well I want the app to remain flexible. most of the users are supposed to be selling products locally, not shipping them. products are supposed to have the option to apply a default tax, which can also be changed in the line item (on the new/edit invoice page) with a drop down select menu.

Comment: Even if it's local, different cities that are next door to one another have different tax rates. The only way a single store is going to have just one tax rate is if the customers come to them (like physically come to the place where the items is being sold), and that store NEVER wants to sell to customers online in other municipalities.

If that's definitely true, or if you want to go with `default tax rate` for now, and worry about more details later, then you should be fine.